# Why does the PUT request give an error using fetch in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, fetch-api

I'm trying to send a PUT request, but the console gives an error.

```
export function putUserData() {
    fetch(`${url}/user/${getCookie("ID")}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${getCookie("TOKEN")}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "first_name": userData.value.first_name,
            "middle_name": userData.value.middle_name,
            "last_name": userData.value.last_name
        })
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        }
        switch (response.status) {
            case 400:
                console.log("Incorrect data");
                break;
        }
    }).then(data => {
        router.push("/auth");
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error("Cannot fetch" + err);
    });
}
```

Network request in console:
[image: Network request in console]

Error in console:
[image: Error in console]

I would like to understand why it does not send a request, although it sends post requests

Comment: The image provided doesn't show the error? May you show the error?

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://imgur.com/W46o7hq

Comment: Because of COR's.   As a default a  `somedomain.com` cannot access `someotherdomain.com` if COR's headers are not set to allow this, seen as your trying to access via localhost it's pretty likely this won't be there.   I would also expect `POST` requests to fail here too,  do you mean `GET`?

Comment: @Keith POST requests are executed successfully https://imgur.com/cAjbF5L

Comment: What are the preflight _response_ headers?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes
JS:
`        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${getCookie("TOKEN")}`
        },`

API:
`func (a *Api) preflightCORS(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
 w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
 w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
}`

Comment: That's because the `POST` request at the SERVER side has said it's allowed, can you see the bit that say `Access-control-allow-origin: *`,  that means they allow anything to connect via `POST`, but it looks like they have not set the same for `PUT`..  There is nothing you can do about it client side, it's the Server side this needs changing..

Comment: Or you can use a self-hosted proxy which will add the proper CORS headers for PUT and relay the request to the original server.

Comment: @Keith But the PUT request is executed in Postman

Comment: Postman the app?  If so it will be fine, CORS is a browser control. Thing like curl would be fine too.  As long as the request is not coming from a browser CORS has no effect, what you might be able to do is get your back end to proxy the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend accepts CORS POST requests, but not PUT. You should modify the headers set there to include PUT using `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header.

PHP example:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods